# Background file indexer (Win, *Nix, crossplatform)

Tags: c, windows, unix, indexing, filesystems

I'm building an equivalent of the OS X `mds` daemon, or `mdworker` which is the backend that `spotlight` uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_%28software%29 to index files (directories are files!) upon creation, deletion and modification.

As seen here, "spotlight" is notified by the OS X kernel of any changes which it responds to - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MetadataIntro/Concepts/HowDoesItWork.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001847-CJBEJBHH

I'm doing this for both Windows, *Nix/Linux and OS X.
Is there any cross platform library that provides hooks or does this?
If not, do you know of any resources for the Win32 API, Nix API, OS X API that will allow me to do this?

I'm fully content with read-only access and being denied access to system sensitive files, but the more I can get, the better!

Here's a list of desktop search engines, some open source - perhaps if any of you have delved into the code, you know if and in that case how they manage it? For example, perhaps Unity Dash does this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_search_engines#Desktop_search_engines

My investigation into the matter is continuing here: https://github.com/Centril/open-spotlight/wiki/Technical-in-depth#watcher

Answer (score 1):

My own research turned up the following resources:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Alteration_Monitor, NFS aware == great for network
http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2004/12/16/fam.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify (Linux only)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamin (Linux => Inotify, FreeBSD => kqueue)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents (OS X > 10.7 (Lion), target >= Yosemite 10.10)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libevent (Platform Independent!)
Even better: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/2047
Winner: https://github.com/libuv/libuv, used by rust via libgreen.
```

Libuv seems to be a great library.